# Small gap between train and test error, does that mean overfitting?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

i am working on a dataset of 368609 samples and 34 features, i wanted to use a neural network to predict latency (real value) using keras, the model has 3 hidden layers, each layer has 1024 neurons, i have used drop_out (50 %) and l2 regularization (0.001) for each hidden layer. The problem is i am getting a test mean absolute error of 3.5505 ms and train mean absolute error of 3.4528. Here, the train error is smaller than test error by a small gap, does this mean that we have an overfitting problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, yet it is still always a good idea to see how your model is generalizing to new data.

Keep something between 10%-20% of your original dataset as a test set and try to predict the output for each record in the test set.

Sometimes when we deal with the same validation set for many attempts of improving our model, we tend to overfit the evaluation dataset as well.

Having 3 different datasets for training, evaluation and testing usually provides a whole solution to overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a high accuracy on your training set and a low accuracy on you test set it often means that your are overfitting. So in you case - no you are probably not overfitting.

Normally you would also have a validation set, so you don't fit your data to the testset.